# Filter an array of objects by an array of dictionaries contained in the object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

So I need to filter an array of objects by an array contained in the object

the object looks like this

```
class thing {

let list = [stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff]

}

class stuff {

var name = "ugly"

}
```

The array looks like this

```
thingArray = [thing, thing, thing, thing]
```

and my code so far looks like this

```
newArray = thingArray.filter { receipt in

return thing.thingArray.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        }
```

So my problem is that I can't get this function to work and what I really need is a way to filter this array of objects by the array contained inside of the object. Any help is definitely appreciated.

p.s. I just tried this to no avail:

```
test = thingArray.filter {$0.list.filter {$0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) == true}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your problem can be solved with something like this:

```
class thing {

init(list: [String]) {
    self.list = list
}

var list: [String]

}

let thingArray = [thing(list: ["one", "two", "three"]), thing(list: ["uno", "due", "tre"]), thing(list: ["uno", "dos", "tres"])]

let searchString = "uno"

let result = thingArray.filter {
    $0.list.contains(searchString)
}

//it will print "uno", "due", "tre"
result.first?.list
```

Comment: If you want to make the search case insensitive you can do this: let result = thingArray.filter {
    ($0.list.filter {
        $0.lowercased() == searchString.lowercased()
        }.first != nil)
}

Comment: @PCD Note that if performance is an issue, you can speed this up by using `Set` instead of `Array`